# Try to solve 'ParallelSaveError' caused by looping and pushing to array. Using Mongoose & Mongo

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am able to find the parent and I am even able to start to save data to my local DB and then it gives me the 'ParallelSaveError'. I have tried moving the .save to after the loop which nothing happens due to scope. I am not sure how to work around this error.

```
.then(shiftInfo => {

        let month = moment().month() + 1,
            day = moment().date(),
            year = moment().year(), 
            today = year+"-"+month+"-"+day;

        CSshift.findOneAndUpdate({date: today}, ({
            date: today,
            shift: shiftInfo[0].thisShift[0].label,
            color: shiftInfo[0].thisShift[0].color                  
        }), {upsert: true},
                function (err, shift){
            // console.log(" Today is "+shift.shift)
        });

        // items.forEach(function(item){
        // copy.push(item);


        var persons = shiftInfo[1].persons



        persons.forEach(function(person){ //THIS IS THE LOOP THAT CAUSES THE PROBLEM

            // console.log(person.name);

            CSshift.findOne({date: today},function(err, date){
                if(err){
                    console.log(err);
                } else {


                    csshift.roster.push({ //I AM TRYING TO PUSH EACH PERSON TO THE DB UNDER CSSHIFT>ROSTER
                        name: person.name,
                        position: person.position,
                        station: person.station
                    });
                    csshift.save(function(err, roster){ //I HAVE MOVED THIS SEGMENT OUT OF THE LOOP W/O SUCCESS.
                        if(err){
                            console.log(err);
                        } else {
                            // console.log(roster);
                        }
                    })
                }
            })
        });
```

I have also tried reading similar problems on here and have not had any success trying what I have read.

Thank you to whom ever is willing to help.

-Adam

Answer (score 0):

So after trying a lot of different things I finally figured it out.

Instead of using a for each loop I used a for loop (which I am more comfortable with), and I moved the loop inside the find statement and then placed the .save outside the loop but inside the find statement.

It works:

```
.then(shiftInfo => {

        let month = moment().month() + 1,
            day = moment().date(),
            year = moment().year(), 
            today = year+"-"+month+"-"+day;

        var persons = shiftInfo[1].persons

        CSshift.findOneAndUpdate({date: today}, ({
            date: today,
            shift: shiftInfo[0].thisShift[0].label,
            color: shiftInfo[0].thisShift[0].color,
        }), {upsert: true},
                function (err, shift){

        });

        CSshift.findOne({date: today}, function(err, shift){

            for(var i=0; i < persons.length; i++){

                csshift.roster.push({name: persons[i].name, position: persons[i].position, station: persons[i].station})

            }
            csshift.save(function(err, roster){
                if(err){
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    // console.log(roster);
                }
            })
        });
```

It now correctly pushes the data to the DB.